using action client and subscriber in the same script
I am using the nav2 api which calls for me to create a node and not use rclpy.spin() on it, because inside some of their function they implement rclpy.spin_until_future_complete().
The issue is that when I want to do other stuff like subscribe to odom topic and monitor it continuously I can’t set a callback and spin() it because later on when I’ll use one of nav2 api function and rclpy.spin_until_future_complete() will be called, at that point I get the ros2 executer error:
File “/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py”, line 711, in spin_once
handler, entity, node = self.wait_for_ready_callbacks(timeout_sec=timeout_sec)
File “/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py”, line 697, in wait_for_ready_callbacks
return next(self._cb_iter)
ValueError: generator already executing

How can I get around this?
Can I subscribe and listen to topics without spinning or any other solution?

Try set timeout by rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(node, timeout_sec=1.5)

In C++ I would have used this line:
rclcpp::spin_some( rclcpp::Node::get_node_base_interface() )

Probably rclpy also support this but I'm not sure, you will need to search it...
You should be careful if you decide to use spin_some. Due to spin_some complete all available queued work without blocking, you should also add a timer function in your Constructor and use spin_some in the timer function:
rclcpp::Node::create_wall_timer( std::chrono::milliseconds( 5 ), std::bind( &Class_Name::Spin, this ) );

Class_Name::Spin() {
    rclcpp::spin_some( rclcpp::Node::get_node_base_interface() );
}

